# Magic Room Illusion - making objects appear when viewed through another object

Tags: transparency

How can this be done in blender?

https://www.instagram.com/p/B_frXZglF0k/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

[image: Magic Room Illusion]

This animation was done in C4D. The feature that I'm looking for is the ability to make an object (e.g. sphere) visible by placing another object (e.g. plane) in between the camera and the sphere. So, the sphere would be invisible to the camera, but becomes visible when seen through the plane.

This is how it was done in C4D:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZRjj89meMs

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a plane (as "window") - give it this material:

[image]

2. Add a box with suzanne in it with this material:

[image]

3. world material:

[image]

4. switch to cycles
5. result

https://youtu.be/vMg0V0UcHPs

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/Qgu4z5T-GV4